# Angular 4 : Strategy to divide application into components

Tags: angular, components, angular2-template, web-component

I am new to angular and so in a project. I have the below senerio.

**Scenario: Onclick of "tile1" (1st picture)... "tile1a","tile1b","tile1c" should appear (2nd picture)... and so on.**

[image]

[image]

Is there a strategy which can help me know how many components and modules should my page be divided into?

Comment: What do you mean by tile1a and tile1? tile1a nd tile1b will contain same details? If so then you should create one saperate component and reuse it dynamically

Comment: for 1st 4 component and 2nd  5 component needed

Comment: No matter what you do and how many component you make, avoid making the components too large. The more concise and specific you can make a component the more reusable and simplistic it can be and that helps to create simpler, better maintained code.

Comment: @TheDictator , Initially on page load tile1, tile2,..... tile5 will be visible and on click of tile1 - tile1a, tile1b... will appear.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it the following way:

1. nav bar component
2. side bar component
3. object list component (where you show the list of tiles)
4. object details component (where you show the tile1a, tile1b, tile1c data for a selected component)

This **master-details** structure is very common in Angular applications and you can find a simple example in the Angular tutorial: https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt3